# Conditionally show/hide unnested label/input form fields based on other input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Sorry for not being clearer in the original post.

I'm trying to hide BOTH the top two form field areas when the bottom checkbox is unchecked and not pass on any values when they are hidden. It is aregistration form for wordpress and I don't want to amend the html, which would make it easier because I could next the labels and inputs inside divs to hide.

shown here the IDs:

(top checkbox)
ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters
(middle radio)
ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts
(bottom checkbox ID)
ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in

@Mosh suggestion below is close, but only hides one.

```js
// Store the `p` node which contains the label.
var collapseParent = $('label[for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts"]').parent();

// Store the `checkbox` that we want to "listen" to
var checkbox = $('[name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_opt_in"]');

// Attach the `change` event on the checkbox and trigger the event so it will fire on page load
checkbox.change(toggle).trigger('change');

// show/hide the `p` node depeneds if the checbox was checked or not
function toggle() {
    collapseParent.toggle(checkbox.is(':checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters">
<span style="display:none;">Do you wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters? *</span>

    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_newsletters" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters" aria-required="true" tabindex="59" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional1">
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">Do you wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters?</label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts">
<span>Do you wish to receive job alerts (digest)? *</span>

    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="weekly" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---0" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;">
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-0" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">weekly</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="daily" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---1" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;">
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-1" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">daily</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="none" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---2" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;">
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-2" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">none</label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_opt_in" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field" value="1" checked="not" tabindex="70">
<span style="color:#be0026;"><strong>=&gt; Yes, I wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters via email &lt;= </strong></span>

    </label>
</p>
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to hide/show. Could you clarify the working process you would like to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @MrBearding I have restated to be more inline with the guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to hide the two extra form sections you will need to use JavaScript. I personally use the jQuery plugin, which from your comments regarding Mosh Feu's answer, isn't going to be a problem.

The code isn't optimal, but as you're unable to change the HTML, we'll work with what we have.

```js
// Store the checkbox we'll be monitoring for changes
var checkTrigger = $('#ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in');

// Store the items we want to show/hide
// I store the 'none' radio button here - if the HTML changes, this will break
// we use this particular radio button further down
var jobAlerts = $('#ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---2');
var newsletterCheck = $('#ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters');

// Check for the change of the checkbox
checkTrigger.change(function() {
  toggleForm(checkTrigger.is(':checked'));
});

// Toggle the form
function toggleForm(isChecked) {
  jobAlerts.parent().toggle(isChecked);
  newsletterCheck.parent().toggle(isChecked);

  // We'll uncheck the red Newsletter checkbox too, if it's being hidden
  // and we'll set the job alerts to none;
  if (!isChecked) {
    newsletterCheck.prop("checked", false);
    jobAlerts.prop("checked", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters">
    <span style="display:none;">Do you wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters? *</span>

  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_newsletters" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters" aria-required="true" tabindex="59" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional1">
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">Do you wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters?</label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts">
    <span>Do you wish to receive job alerts (digest)? *</span>

  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="weekly" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---0" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;">
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-0" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">weekly</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="daily" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---1" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;">
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-1" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">daily</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="none" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---2" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;">
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-2" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">none</label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_opt_in" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field" value="1" checked="not" tabindex="70">
    <span style="color:#be0026;"><strong>=&gt; Yes, I wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters via email &lt;= </strong></span>

  </label>
</p>
```

The jQuery code assumes that the HTML won't change. If the ID values of the checkboxes change, then the jQuery will break.

I know you don't want to change the HTML here, but from a UI point of view, it doesn't make sense that the bottom checkbox hides those above it. Users read left-to-right, top-to-bottom and having the bottom checkbox interacting with elements above it, this general rule is broken.

You should consider moving the triggering checkbox to the top.

Comment: LOVELY. I see the bottom statements clear the values for hidden fields, too!

Yes, ideally I want to place the hidden fields under the trigger input. However, currently the above code is part of the registration/profile forms for s2member plugin for wordpress (it uses native WP registration form and just appends the above code which is a combination of custom fields (the top two I want to hide) and the bottom checkbox (which is the the opt-in for mail listserve). So the top two fields are implemented completely separate from the bottom one, which effectively always comes last.

Comment: I would like to override the registration template and change the order of fields but as of yet I haven't seen much documentation for it. I'm not sure if I can just do it with CSS or if I it would be more direct to change the php file.

Comment: I don't have any experience with that plugin, but when you add your custom fields in wp-admin, can you not add them in a particular order?

Comment: I can change the order of the custom fields just fine. the problem is the bottom field (here "=> Yes, I wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters via email <=") isn't a custom field. It is an integration of a listserve (in this case Mailchimp). It is in a fixed position within the registration/profile forms at the very bottom, which I don't like. Am trying to find a way to change the order now

Answer (score 2):

This code is a little beat ugly but this is the "cost" of not changing the `html`.

Please read the notes within the code so you can understand what I did.

If you want to do this functionality to other checkbox/radio buttons, just change the selectors of the elements (label/checkbox or p node)

```js
// Store the `p` node which contains the label.
var collapseParent = $('label[for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts"]').parent();

// Store the `checkbox` that we want to "listen" to
var checkbox = $('[name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_newsletters"]');

// Attach the `change` event on the checkbox and trigger the event so it will fire on page load
checkbox.change(toggle).trigger('change');

// show/hide the `p` node depeneds if the checbox was checked or not
function toggle() {
  collapseParent.toggle(checkbox.is(':checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters">
<span style="display:none;">Do you wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters? *</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_newsletters" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters" aria-required="true" tabindex="59" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional1"> <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-newsletters" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">Do you wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters?</label></p>
    
    <p>
<label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts">
<span>Do you wish to receive job alerts (digest)? *</span></label><br>
<input type="radio" value="weekly" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---0" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;"> <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-0" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">weekly</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="daily" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---1" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;"> <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-1" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">daily</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="none" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_jobalerts" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts---2" aria-required="true" tabindex="60" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field s2conditional2" style="color:#006699;"> <label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-jobalerts-2" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-op-l" style="display:inline !important; margin:0 !important;">none</label></p>
    
    <p>
<label for="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in">
<input type="checkbox" name="ws_plugin__s2member_custom_reg_field_opt_in" id="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field-opt-in" class="ws-plugin--s2member-custom-reg-field" value="1" checked="not" tabindex="70">
<span style="color:#be0026;"><strong>=&gt; Yes, I wish to receive JETAAUK Newsletters via email &lt;= </strong></span></label></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mosh, the collapseParent looks great. I changed it around as I want to collapse the top two boxes based on the bottom checkbox being checked. How can you collapse two fields? Are you able to call collapseParent with multiple nodes in the same instance?

https://jsfiddle.net/8ACN9/3/
Here's the code amended to hide the top field:

Comment: You can do this with many node as you want. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8ACN9/56/

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I got both to hide just fine but also I now see that the above doesn't clear the input values, it only hides them visually. I'll be attempting to use @MrBearding 's solution below as it clears values on the hidden fields when hidden, effectively reseting them.